# Gitlab-ci multiple repositories trigger one build

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We have setup and perfectly running gitlab + gitlab-ci installation. We are now looking how to do cross-project builds. Our project is divided into several repositories and everything is joined during build process via composer.

What I would like to achieve is - when you commit to any of those repositories, they trigger main repository to get built. I was trying to achieve this via webhooks, unfortunately I need a lot of information about commit from the main repository, that I don't have.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I updated gitlab-ci code a little bit: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci/commit/7c7066b0d5a35097a04bb31848d6b622195940ed

I can now call the api.